# Webpack removing empty html tags?

Tags: webpack, handlebars.js

I use Webpack 4 with handlebars and there are many "default" optimizations for production mode I guess. I've googled about an hour for now and didn't find a solution...

In development mode empty tags are working. For example

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

or

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

If I add a non breaking space for example, the tags will be compiled in dist, but its very ugly...

```
<span class="caret">&nbsp;</span>
```

But after npm run build, these empty html tags are gone / stripped out. I have no idea why :(

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` in your `webpack.config` you can configure the minification like this:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  minify: {
    removeEmptyElements: false,
  },
})
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!

But why is something like this not documented in the webpack documentation? Very annoying :-(...

Comment: @RolfSchupfinger It's actually quite well documented, but you have to know where to look ;). You can read about the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` options [here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options).